# How to integrate Debian netinstall into existing PXE configuration?

Tags: debian, pxe, tftp

Debian provides an archive with files for PXE boot network installation [as explained here](https://wiki.debian.org/PXEBootInstall). The contents of the archive is meant be copied into an TFTP server's root directory and includes a pxelinux.cfg/default. With this setup, a PXE client will then offer a menu for Debian installation only.

I already have a PXE configuration for my TFTP server that provides various other boot options and would like to add the Debian netinstall as an additional option. I extracted the files from the archive into a subdirectory debian/stretch of the TFTP server. What do I have to put into pxelinux.cfg/default to forward to the Debian netinstall menu? Do I have to modify the Debian files to fit into the existing PXE setup?

Comment: you may be interested in some of my tftp setup.  it includes scripts for downloading and unpacking debian installer, clonezilla, and gparted and setting up menus for multiple versions of them.   https://github.com/craig-sanders/tftp-stuff

Answer (score 0):

All you need is in  [**Debian GNU/Linux Installation Guide**](https://www.debian.org/releases/stable/amd64/ch04s05.html.en).
If you have TFTP working, and you know how add additional image to pxe you need to copy image from [there](http://http.us.debian.org/debian/dists/stretch/main/installer-amd64/current/images/netboot/).

!  *This links is for AMD64 architecture, but for others procedure is similar.*

Comment: I'm not sure what image you are referring to. I would like to add an entry to my existing PXE boot menu that includes the menu pxelinux.cfg/default from netboot.tar.gz as a submenu. Sort of what is called "Same TFTP chaining" in [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/35409/pxe-boot-chaining-to-hardcoded-tftp-server/202511#202511). Except, there is no pxeboot.0 in Debian.

Comment: You have pxelinux.0 on my second link you need to specyfy it inne menu config.

Comment: Could you be a little more specific? What would the entry to pxelinux.cfg/default look like?

Comment: Ok, i was not understand, what you wany to do. In boot-screen are menus for pxe you can include it. It is in default file (include debian-installer/amd64/boot-screens/menu.cfg default debian-installer/amd64/boot-screens/vesamenu.c32 prompt 0 timeout 0)